# Error al subir aplicacion web a servidor

Tags: java, aplicación-web, tomcat

He realizado una *aplicación Web* en **Javaweb** utilizando librerías `ICEFACES`. Lo he probado localmente con **Tomcat** y funciona bien. Mi problema es al subir mi `app` a un servidor remoto. Estoy probando en este *hosting* que soporta `j2ee`:

> http://s156.eatj.com/index.jsp

Luego de cargar el archivo `WAR` que se me genera, intento arrancar el servicio y me sale el siguiente error:

> FALLO - No se pudo arrancar la aplicación en trayectoria de contexto
>   /SoftwareSJRApacheTomcat  FALLO - Encontrada excepción
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SoftwareSJRApacheTomcat]]

Estoy utilizando **JDK 1.7** y **Tomcat 7.0**.

¿Cómo soluciono el error? Gracias

Comment: ¿Has compilado con la misma versión del JDK que la instalada en el servidor?

Comment: Si, 1.7 en ambos casos

Comment: @DavidBrito revisa [estos](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5494089/4092887) [enlaces](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4881087/4092887).

Comment: `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException` debe tener un `Caused by:`  Cuál es ?

Comment: ese es todo el error que me da